# How to securely authorize custom Lambda resolvers for Cognito groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have a custom Query which is attached to a custom Lambda resolver. In that Lambda resolver I want to reject requests that come from users not from a particular Cognito user group. Which property should I check in the event object in the Lambda resolver? What is the secure way to do this as I don't want the client to add a field manually to the request and then cause the request to succeed and not rejected? Is it identity.claims.cognito:groups or identity.claims.groups?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: dentity.claims.cognito:groups or identity.claims.groups